# Strange randomness behaviour

Tags: java, javafx, random

Trying to make ants simulator using javaFX

I've had a problem that : the ants are not distributed equally on the whole frame.
At first I had a problem to periodically update each ant **at a random rate** and **to a random direction** so say for example an ant will change it's direction after 0.5 s and after that it will change it randomly after 0.3s ..etc
I've managed to solve this using this method,it's a bit complicated I'll try to make it as simple as I can:

Create an array `chosenAnts` which has a length of `antCount/2` , this array , holds the **indices** of the randomly chosen ants that will change their direction in the next X seconds.

Using `PauseTransition` I loop through the `chosenAnts` array and then update the positions of the chosen ants , these ants will change their directions at the same moment to a random directions .

Update the indices that are in the `chosenAnts` array randomly , this provides the next random indices that'll be chosen for the next queue:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < chosenAnts.length ;i++){
chosenAnts[i] = (int)(Math.random() * antCount);
}
```

Finally,update the position of the ants by updating the velocity on the x,y just like this with the above code, note that `xvel` and `yvel` are arrays that hold the velocity of each ant on both x ,y ; and please dont look to the right side it's just a mess in order to make the ant behave correctly and not crazily, in other words, the direction will be within the red triangle
:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < chosenAnts.length ;i++){
    chosenAnts[i] = (int)(Math.random() * antCount); 
            xvel[chosenAnts[i]] = ((xvel[chosenAnts[i]] - 0.2) + Math.random() * (xvel[chosenAnts[i]] + .2)) % 1;
            yvel[chosenAnts[i]] = ((yvel[chosenAnts[i]] - 0.2) + Math.random() * (yvel[chosenAnts[i]] + .2)) % 1;
    }
```

And this is how it looks like with 100 000 ants ,after few minutes of the start of the sim ,they keep rolling at the same density order forever,  **note that**  the position of the colony is literally on the buttom right which is the opposite of where they are dense and there are borders.

Edit:
here's the whole 112 lines program:
https://github.com/yahiaDZz/AntsSim

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Randomize()`, the velocity update trends towards negative values, making the ants trend towards the upper-left corner.

```java
// Abbreviated formula, without the array lookup
xvel = ((xvel - 0.2) + Math.random() * (xvel + .2)) % 1;

// Should probably be one of the following
xvel = ((xvel - 0.1) + Math.random() * (xvel + .2)) % 1;
xvel = ((xvel - 0.2) + Math.random() * (xvel + .4)) % 1;
```

Remember the formula from the initial assignment:

```java
xvel[i] = -1 + Math.random() * 2;
```